# Adding a link to images in the footer

Tags: html, css, image, footer

My footer contains three images and i want to add a link to (coyright and companysite) that once you click on the image, it takes you to the website i tried different methods i found here but its not working with me. what should i add?

The page code:

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">

        <div id="header">

        </div>

    <div id="main">

        <div id="content">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>



<div id="footer">


    <div id="img-1">


    </div>

</div>


</body>
```

the CSS:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;} 


html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: url('../../fresh/img/bg.png') repeat;

    }

#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    }

#header {
background: url('../../fresh/img/header.png') no-repeat top center;
display:block;
text-indent:-9000px;
width: 100%;
height: 237px;
}

#main {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 200px;}  
#content {
    background: url('../../fresh/img/log-in.png') no-repeat top center;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 201px;


}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -200px;     height: 200px;
    clear:both;
    } 


body:before {
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;
}





#img-1 {
    bottom:0;
    height:200px;
    background : url('../img/footer.png') center no-repeat,
                 url('../img/companysite.png') left no-repeat,
                 url('../img/copyright.png') right no-repeat,  ;
    }
```

Comment: What were the things you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to link a website.(If you use html)

**1.By using Anchor tag** (Most prefered method)

```
<a href="targetUrl.html">Your element tags like p,span,img,... </a>
```

**2.By using window.location function**

```
<div onclick="window.location='http://www.yahoo.com'" style="cursor:pointer"></div>
```

[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbz90qng/)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your img tag in a link tag like so:

```
<a href="my_url.html"><img src="my_img.jpg></a>
```

Then any part of the image will be a clickable link.

Comment: You need one more edit on your code ;-): `<a href="my_url.html"><img src="my_img.jpg"></a>`

Comment: @Broco sorry I dont see a difference? What did i miss?

Comment: The quote after jpg ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="img-1" onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com'" style="cursor:pointer">

 </div>
```

Comment: I would rather use an `a` tag. That is what they are used for and better for SEO purposes too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add images inside anchor elements as shown:

```
<div id="footer">

   <div id="img-1">
      <a href="yourUrl1"><img src="yourImage1"/></a>
      <a href="yourUrl2"><img src="yourImage2"/></a>
      <a href="yourUrl3"><img src="yourImage3"/></a>
   </div>

</div>
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are placing all images as backgrounds in a div. Use three separate images instead:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="img-1">
         <a href="url1.html"><img src="../img/footer.png" alt="" /></a>
         <a href="url2.html"><img src="../img/companysite.png" alt="" /></a>
         <a href="url3.html"><img src="../img/copyright.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And remove the backgrounds from the CSS:

```
#img-1 {
    bottom:0;
    height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
<div id="img-1">
</div>
```

into

```
<a href="your desired link">
    <div id="img-1">
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to clarify that on one HTML page you cannot use more than one same name ID tag  or else you will get W3C validation error on your page.

In order to achieved what you are looking for is as under:

**//This is your HTML code**

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="img-1">
         <a href="copyrights.html">CopyRights</a>
    </div>
    <div id="img-2">
         <a href="company.html">Company</a>
    </div>
</div>

**//Here is your CSS Code**
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -200px;     height: 200px;
    clear:both;
    bottom:0;
    height:200px;
    background : url('../img/footer.png') center no-repeat
    } 

#img-1 {
   url('../img/companysite.png') left no-repeat;
    }
#img-2 {
   url('../img/copyright.png') right no-repeat,  ;
    }
```

Comment: Check your image path in the above code as ../ before image path means go up one folder and find images folder. If you have images folder in the same folder where your html or php files are located then remove the ../ and your path should look like: 

 url('img/companysite.png') left no-repeat;

Hopefully it should work as I have not tested the code